# Design responsivo da versão mobile funcionando no emulador dos navegadores, porém no próprio dispositivo não?

Tags: html, css, viewport

Nos emuladores do Chrome, Mozilla e Edge estão funcionando perfeitamente a visão dos dispositivos móveis, porém no celular ele não fica a mesma coisa. Estou utilizando a tag `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou especificar o `width=device-width`. Ele ajusta a dimensão da *viewport* (área de visão) fazendo com que a página se ajuste ao tamanho da tela exibindo os elementos em tamanho real.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Além de que faltou fechar as aspas duplas do atributo `content`:

```
...content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0>
```